# is there a way I can add or remove some plugin options?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I don't know if my question is clear.[image: this image might make it clear.]

I want to add and remove some options in the circled section of the image.

thanks.

Comment: And what have you tried? (code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you might be talking about adding `plugin_action_links` such as,

```
Settings | Deactivate | Delete | Visit Site
```

As seen on the Plugin management page for all plugins.

I was going to take an example from one of my plugins however here is an example that's much simpler to follow from Pippin via guest post at WPMods [HERE](http://www.wpmods.com/adding-plugin-action-links/) and if you don't know Pippin, he's one to follow for all things Plugin Development.

```
function our_plugin_action_links($links, $file) {
    static $this_plugin;

    if (!$this_plugin) {
        $this_plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    }

    // check to make sure we are on the correct plugin

    if ($file == $this_plugin) {

        // the anchor tag and href to the URL we want. For a "Settings" link, this needs to be the url of your settings page

        $settings_link = '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=font-uploader.php">Settings</a>';

        // add the link to the list

        array_unshift($links, $settings_link);
    }

    return $links;
}

add_filter('plugin_action_links', 'our_plugin_action_links', 10, 2);
```

Fairly self explanatory (see inline comments for a break down of whats occurring). You can also add more than one link if your plugin requires it.